# Cname to replace namesever change

Tags: nameserver, cname-record, dns-zone, cloudflare, a-record

I'm using Cloudflare and they want me to change my nameserver from ns1.mydomain.com  to ns1.lamedomain.com

Can I use a cname record to keep ns1.mydomain.com or should I use "A" record and link to the IP of ns1.lamedomain.com?

please give me an example?
thanks in advance.

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169006-Can-I-get-vanity-or-custom-nameservers-using-Cloudflare-

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What difference does it make what your name servers are, no-one sees them. I think you need to do a little reading on how [DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/) and [CloudFlare work](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205177068-Step-1-How-does-Cloudflare-work-). Other than what Michael has said you have to use CloudFlare name servers, or use an [affiliated hosting company](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202320534-Can-I-use-Cloudflare-without-changing-my-nameservers-to-Cloudflare-).

Comment: I selling hosting on my server when i build a website for a client and its good branding to have a nameserver with you main domain on it.

Comment: The people who know to ask for this are going to build their own websites. As a practical matter it makes no real difference to anybody.

Comment: ... As Tim said, sign up for an affiliate, you'll get a CNAME for the web record, using their API which works with many web panels like interworx, plesk, cpanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I selling hosting on my server when i build a website for a client and
>   its good branding to have a nameserver with you main domain on it.

Too many web hosters think that they should/need to host DNS for their website customers... and too many of them don't know enough about DNS and the management of DNS, which invariably leads to problems for the customer. If you're asking this question then you probably shouldn't be entertaining the thought of hosting DNS for your website customers. It has nothing to do with branding. Nobody cares where the DNS is hosted and most website customers wouldn't know DNS if it smacked them in the face. Do yourself and your customers a favor and leave their DNS alone. There's no technical reason that you need/should host DNS for your website customers.

Comment: Also switch to cloudflare, they're one of (if not the) top dns providers in the net.

Comment: Glad to help...